# Keep pen width when resizing from toolbar

Tags: inkscape

How can I keep the width of a line the same when I resize it from the textbox in toolbar to a number that I need?
the lock icon does nothing in this case. This is very annoying :(

So I got this line with W = 15

[image: Line before]

As soon as I change the W, the H or width changes too (W from 15 to 100 in this case):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your path only consists of a stroke, disable the 'When scaling objects, scale the stroke width by the same proportion' button in the toolbar:

[image: Screenshot from the question with button highlighted.]